# Symmetric system of equations given by sums of powers

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

Let $u_k = \alpha_1^k + \cdots + \alpha_n^k$, where $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{C}$ and $n \ge 1$.

> How do I find $\alpha_i$ given that $u_k = k$ for $k = 1, \dots, n$?

If it helps, I suspect that $\alpha_i$ are roots of $P(x) = x^n - \left( \frac{1}{1!}x^{n-1} + \frac{1}{2!}x^{n-2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n!} \right)$.

**EDIT:** As noted in the comments by @Servaes, I suspected wrongly.

Comment: Unfortunately, the $\alpha_i$ are in general not the roots of your polynomial $P$. They are the roots of
$$\sum_{i=0}^n\left(\sum_{\substack{i_1,\ldots,i_n\geq0\\\sum_{j=1}^n j\cdot i_j=i}}(-1)^i\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{-u_k^{i_k}}{i_k!k^{i_k}}\right)X^{n-i}=\sum_{i=0}^n\left(\sum_{\substack{i_1,\ldots,i_n\geq0\\\sum_{j=1}^n j\cdot i_j=i}}\prod_{k=1}^n(-1)^{i+i_k}(i_k!)^{-1}\right)X^{n-i}.$$

Comment: @Servaes How did you derive that equation?

Comment: The coefficients of this polynomial are expressions for the elementary symmetric polynomials in terms of the given power sums. One can prove that these expressions hold by induction, but this is nasty, and is another question entirely. If you're looking for a reference, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities#Expressing_elementary_symmetric_polynomials_in_terms_of_power_sums) is your friend.